# Get and modify shapes in docx documents with python?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I would like to open and manipulate shapes in a Microsoft Word(docx) documents.
I tried `python-docx` and went through the docs but nothing looked like it could work.

By manipulating I mean change color, width, height, etc.

Here is an example docx with a rectangle shape:

[image: docx doc]

Is there a solution for python that can solve this ?